# jquery accordion click toggle class

Tags: jquery

i want in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EYpdC/) when tab slide up remove class active and add active class in open tab

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#accordian li h3").click(function(){
                //slide up all the link lists
                $("#accordian ul .row").slideUp();
                //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
                if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
                {
                    $(this).next().slideDown();

                }
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#accordian li h3").click(function () {
         var $parent = $(this).parent();
         if ($parent.hasClass('active')) return;
         //slide up all the link lists
         $("#accordian ul .row").slideUp();
         $(this).next().slideDown(function () {
             $parent.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
         });
     })
 })
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EYpdC/7/)

Comment: look this http://jsfiddle.net/mA97v/

I put some input but when i click the second time to slidedown don't show

Comment: You are nesting some divs class row inside the main div class row and you shouldn't: http://jsfiddle.net/mA97v/1/

Comment: Thank you very mush my frind

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EYpdC/1/)

Answer (score 1):

first remove all active class. then add to the current clicked one's. [Demo: Accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/EYpdC/3/)

```
$('#accordian li').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
```